# how to switch in R from columns to series

Tags: r

So I have this data in R

```
Afghanistan  48.673
Albania  76.918
Algeria  73.131
Angola  51.093
Argentina  75.901
```

How can I switch the numbers into a series? I need them to appear in the following format

```
Data=c(48.673,76.918,73.131,51.093,75.901)
```

without typing each of the numbers. If I use just copy and past,they will remain as a column and certain commands won't work unless they are in the series format.
I'm new in R so i apologize for not using the appropiate language.
I hope I made myself clear and that you can help me

Thanks!

Comment: If you dataset is a 2 column `data.frame`, you can just do `data[,2]` to convert to vector.

Comment: Can you post the output of a `dput` of the variable name holding the "data in R"?